# How much is the minimum of $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}$

Tags: inequality

$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}$$

We have three unknowns if they were two it were easy but I have no idea when it becomes three unknowns any hints?

**note**:There isn't any information about value of $a$,$b$ and $c$

Comment: USE AM-GM inequality

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee.How should I use it?

Comment: If $a=-10^{100000} $ and $b=c=1$ then $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}=?$. Are $a,b,c>0 \, ?$

Comment: No there is no information in the question?

Comment: so $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\to -\infty$

Comment: Yes the test also contains that.

Comment: @Behrouz Maleki.Then I think the answer below is wrong.Yes?Do you have any proofs for your answer?

Comment: Your question Is meaningless

Comment: Why?It is on morshed grade $8$ book.

Comment: It is wrong....

Comment: Yes I know what do you mean this can be as minimum as you think.I m confused too.But it has also an answer that it hasn't minimum is that correct?

Comment: Fix  $b,c$ then $\underset{a\to -\infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\left( \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} \right)=-\infty $

Comment: Thank you It's better to post as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using AM-GM inequality, we have

> $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} \geq 3 \cdot \sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{b}{c} \cdot \frac{c}{a}}=3$$

The equality is indeed attained when

> $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{a}\tag{1}$$

From $(1)$, we must have $a=b=c$ to attain equality.

**Note:**

- The AM-GM inequality holds true in this case, only when $a,b,c>0$ or $a,b,c<0$. This can be seen by substituting $x=\frac{a}{b},y=\frac{b}{c},
  z=\frac{c}{a}$ and setting $x,y,z >0$
- A simple counter-example to show that the sign of $a,b,c$ must be same is $a=b=-1$ and $c=1$.(This can also be proved using contradiction in the previous argument.)
- If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and no other condition is given, then as pointed out by @Behrouz Maleki, $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} \rightarrow -\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

Another idea to see this is the following : 
Let's supoose we have $$f(a,b,c)= \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}, \hspace{5mm}a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}^{*}$$
We have 
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}= \frac{1}{b}-\frac{c}{a^2} , \hspace{2mm} \frac{\partial f}{\partial b} = \frac{1}{c} - \frac{a}{b^2}, \hspace{2mm} \frac{\partial f}{\partial c}=\frac{1}{a} -\frac{b}{c^2} $

So if we demand $\nabla f = 0 $ or equivalently
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}= 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{c}{a^2}=\frac{1}{b} \hspace{5mm} (1)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{a}{b^2}=\frac{1}{c}\hspace{5mm} (2)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial c} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{b}{c^2}=\frac{1}{a}\hspace{5mm} (3)$$
From (1) and (2) we have $$\frac{b}{a^2} = \frac{1}{c} \text{    and  } \frac{a}{b^2}=\frac{1}{c}$$ which gives us $b^3=a^3 \Rightarrow b=a$ and (3) gives us $c^2=a^2 \Rightarrow  c = \pm\sqrt{a}$

The Hessian matrix of f is 
\begin{equation*}
\nabla^2 f
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2ca^{-3} &  -{b^{-2}}  & -a^{-2}   \\
-b^{-2} & 2ab^{-3}&    -c^{-2}        \\
 -a^{-2} & -c^{-2} & 2bc^{-3}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
det(\nabla^2 f) =
(2ca^{-3})
\begin{vmatrix}
2ab^{-3} & -c^{-2}  \\ 
-c^{-2} & 2bc^{-3}  
\end{vmatrix}
-(-b^{-2})
\begin{vmatrix}
-b^{-2} & -c^{-2}  \\ 
-a^{-2} & 2bc^{-3}  
\end{vmatrix}
+(-a^{-2})
\begin{vmatrix}
-b^{-2} &2ab^{-3}  \\ 
-a^{-2} & c^{-2} 
\end{vmatrix} = 
\cdots = 8a^{-2}b^{-2}c^{-2} - 4a^{-3}c^{-1} +2b^{-3}c^{-3}-2a^{-2}b^{-2}c^{-2}-2a^{-3}b^{-3}
\end{equation*}
If we see when the gradient is zero , we have two cases , 1)$a=b,c=a$ and 2) $a=b,c=-a$

For the first case the last determinant gives us 
$$1) : \hspace{7mm} 6a^{-6}-4a^{-4}$$
and for the second case 
$$2) : \hspace{7mm} 2a^{-6}+4a^{-4}$$
For the second case we can't have local minimum since if we replace $c=-a$ to the hessian matrix , then we have a principal minor (the element (1,1)) of the hesian) determinant equals to -2a^{-4} which is obviously negative for every $a\neq 0 $

For the first case since we can find $a$ such that $6a^{-6}-4a^{-4} >0$ , so we can moving forward two the second principali minor determinant which is the above :

\begin{equation*}
\begin{vmatrix}
2a^{-2} & -\frac{1}{a^2}\\
-\frac{1}{a^2} & 2a^{-2}
\end{vmatrix}
=\cdots = 3a^{-4} >0, \hspace{7mm} \forall a \in \mathbb{R}^{*}
\end{equation*}
The next move is to see the element (1,1) of the hessian matrix which is $2a^{-2}$ so its positive again for all alpha except zero. 
So for a=b=c we have local minimum which is globally because all the local minimum have the same value $1+1+1=3$.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the best I can think of, [that you stated the *minimum*, not the *least absolute value*]:

- if $A$ is some arbitrarily *large* negative, i.e. $-10^{100}$
- and $B$ is some arbitrarily *small* positive, i.e. $10^{-100}$ (so therefore $A/B= -10^{200}$)
- and $C$ is some arbitrarily *non-zero* number

As $B$ decreases, $B/C$ approaches $0$, and as $A$ approaches $-\infty$,  $C/A$ approaches $0$ as well, but $A/B$ approaches $-\infty$.

As for minimizing the absolute value, that would take much more complex [or just different] maths. To summarize, $A=-\infty$ and $B=1/\infty$ and $C\ne0$

I am almost certain you meant minimizing the absolute value... but just in case, here's what I could think of.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! Before you post a question/answer, please read about formatting [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). By tradition, I also invite you to read the [tour page](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and provide a link to the [help center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help). I've edited your answer so that people can understand what you meant. See you :)